# DB Fk/Pk keys performance

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, erd

In our DB we have a single centric table with millions of rows that is constantly being inserted and updated.
This table has a single column acting as the unique identifier and is used to link the content of this table with mutliple tables with a one to many relation.

This means that wehn inserting entry to, say, USERS table, in the same transaction also USERS_PETS and USERS_PARENTS (and 10 more) will be populated, with multiple rows, based on the same unique identifier from the main table.

Since the application using this DB is constantly inserting new entries and updating existing ones the relation between these tables is kept only at the application level (i.e. logical ERD instead of handling this via FK/PK decelrations).

**Questions:**

1. Is this correct to assume that from pure performnces point of view, this is the best approach?
2. Is there a way to set these keys (so that the DB will be more self descriptive) without impacting performaces?

Comment: I would **never EVER** give up data integrity (PK/FK relationships) just for the sake of performance....

Comment: In order for any useful statement, you'll need to be more specific about the database system (and version) you're using, and what those tables and keys are like.....

Comment: Thanks mark. What if the client wil not take your softwre and you are left with no client because it doesn't run fast enough?  Software wise, We use both DB2 and Oracle (11g) so I'm looking for a general insight rather than a specific solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, for the same reason we use seatbelts in cars even when we are in a hurry. The difference is negligeble and totally not worth it.
2. Some specific dbms vendors may offer a way of declaring constraints while not enforcing them. In Oracle for example, you can specify the Integrity Constraint State as `DISABLE NOVALIDATE`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the worst possible approach and I guarantee you will have data integrity issues eventually. Data integrity is far more critical than performance. This is stupid and short-sighted.

Comment: Perhaps I could be more diplomatic, but stuff like this makes me so angry.

Comment: Don't be - it's **good** to be **VERY** clear about those priorities!

Comment: +1 - we need to stick to proper principles of normalization, what is especially annoying are the people who go around declaring that these things are acceptable in any way.

Comment: +1 for "stupid and shortsighted". I can make most databases run *really* fast if they don't have to return the right answers.

Comment: I'm a new commer to an application running strong for over 6 years. There are no data integrity issues in the software because it is handled in the application logic. But that a side, your strong view on tis is much appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You base data integrity on hope. Hope doesn't scale well.

And there's no such thing as "pure performance point of view". Unless, that is, you never read from the database. If you only insert, never update, never delete, and **never read**, you can make a case that there exists a "pure performance point of view". But if you ever update, delete, or **read**, then performance isn't a point--it's more like a surface or a solid, and all you can do is move the balancing point around among inserts, updates, deletes, and reads.

And, because somebody reading this still won't get it, the **most critical** part of **read** performance is getting back the **right answer**. If you can't guarantee the right answer, sensible people won't care how marginally faster your inserts are.